# Getting invalid method reference

Tags: java, lombok

I am working on a Junit5 integration testing with spring-test-mongo. While executing the below code, I am facing **invalid method reference** error.

```
import com.jupiter.tools.spring.test.mongo.annotation.MongoDataSet;
import com.jupiter.tools.spring.test.mongo.junit5.meta.annotation.MongoDbIntegrationTest;
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;

@MongoDbIntegrationTest
public class JUnit5ExampleTest {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Test
    @MongoDataSet(value = "/dataset/bar_dataset.json")
    void testPopulatingByMongoDataSet() throws Exception {

        Bar simpleDoc = mongoTemplate.findById("55f3ed00b1375a48e618300b", Bar.class);

        Assertions.assertThat(simpleDoc)
                .isNotNull()
                .extracting(Bar::getId, Bar::getData);

    }
}
```

Bar.class

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Bar {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String data;
}
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
    testImplementation 'com.jupiter-tools:spring-test-mongo:0.15'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.5.4'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.5.4'
    testImplementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you're using different versions of lombok for test and build?

Comment: @Thomas: I have tried the latest version (lombok:1.18.20) but still facing the same issue

Comment: I'm not a user of lombok myself so I might be missing something but I don't see you using any annotation processor like described here: https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle. Does this even work in your normal (non-test) build?

Comment: I have tried that but still not working.